# Django - ORM - datetime field different formats

Tags: django, date, datetime, model, format

i am currently working on a Django app where every single *DateTimeField* should have the exact same format... to start with, this is my abstract model:

```
from django.db import models

class AbstractModel(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Both *created* and *updated* field have the same format, like this:

```
2019-01-01 12:12:12.123456+00 # right
```

BUT: When i add some other *DateTimeField* to any model, like:

```
some_other_field = models.DateTimeField()
```

and save it via *django-admin*, it gets this format in database:

```
2019-01-01 12:12:12+00 # wrong
```

WHY ?! Right now i have two different *DateTimeField* formats in my database, which is conceptually very bad..

Can anybody help me out? I simply want one format (the upper one) in every single datetime field..

Settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Which database are you using?
I suspect you want to see the value 2019-01-01 12:12:12.000000+00

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud use default value for custome datetime field:

```
some_other_field = models.DateTimeField()
```

and select default format value like **created** or **updated** field :

```
[
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '2006-10-25 14:30:59.000200'
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
    '%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/2006 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/06 14:30:59.000200'
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06'
]
```

A list of formats that will be accepted when inputting data on a datetime field. 
you can read more django datetime format [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats).

Comment: well ok.. but where do i specify a global format?.. because DATETIME_FORMAT in settings.py make no difference..